# Jquery UI dialog Append to Div

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm creating a Jquery-UI dialog using the code below.

```
 var dynDiv = document.createElement("div");
       document.getElementById("divparent").appendChild(dynDiv);
      dialog_box(dynDiv, buttons);


      function dialog_box(dynDiv, dialog_buttons) {    
        $.each(dialog_buttons, function (index, props) {
            $("#" + dynDiv.id).append('<span id="btn' + dynDiv.id + props.id + '">' + props.text + '</span>');
            $('#btn' + dynDiv.id + props.id).button().on("click", {
                param: props,divid: dynDiv.id
            }, props.handler);


        });


    $("#" + dynDiv.id).dialog({
        modal: true,
        appendTo: "#divparent",
        show: "puff",hide: "explode",resizable: true,closeOnEscape: false,
        minWidth: 200, 
        minHeight: 150

    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DOmEl/qNGEw/41/
According to this a jquery dialog should be created and append to **divparent**. But its not appending as expected, its created a seperate node and formed the dialog. Can anyone figure out where i made wrong?

Comment: What version of jQuery UI are you using (appendTo: version added 1.10.0) ?

Comment: Im using jquery-1.10.2.js

Comment: @user833985 That's the jQuery version. What version of jQuery **UI**?

Comment: show complete js code

Comment: A sample fiddle added.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery UI How to Open a Dialog, append to a div not the body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028169/jquery-ui-how-to-open-a-dialog-append-to-a-div-not-the-body)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dialog actually did appendTo `#divparent1`.
The problem seems to be that its position is absolute.

Try changing the position of `#divparent` to `absolute` again apply this fix:

```
$("#" + dynDiv.id).dialog({
    modal: true,
    appendTo: "#divparent1",
    show: "puff",
    hide: "explode",
    resizable: true,
    closeOnEscape: false,
    minWidth: 200,
    minHeight: 150,
    position: { my: "left top", of: "left top"}
});
```

You can check the result here: http://jsfiddle.net/qNGEw/46/