# Login controls and jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

### Short version

Why don't ASP.NET login controls such as `asp:ChangePassword` and `asp:PasswordRecovery` work inside [jQuery dialogs](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)?

### Details

I have a `GridView` showing the list of my users. In the GridView, I have added a `TemplateField` containing a hyperlink named "Change Password". Clicking this link will, among other operations, add the following script to the page:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "ShowChangePwd", "$(document).ready(function() { $(""#ChangePwdDialog"").dialog(""open""); });", True)
```

`ChangePwdDialog` is a `div` with `asp:ChangePassword` control in it. As I run the project and click the Change button in the GridView, things work fine and the ChangePassword div appears as a dialog. But when I fill the TextBoxes (current password, new password, confirm password) and click Change Password button, it doesn't appear to do anything. The dialog simply remains open.

Is this because the jQuery dialog somehow blocks any other buttons from processing? If so, what's my way forward?

Comment: dlg.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first")); Just add your dialog to your form. Then show it.

Comment: You should have posted this as the answer

Comment: This a similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028169/jquery-ui-how-to-open-a-dialog-append-to-a-div-not-the-body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aristos is correct but doesn't offer work around.

You need to cut (using jQuery) the modal dialog DOM nodes and reinsert them into the main asp form tag.

As per Phx comment the jQuery looks something like:

`dlg.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));`

Add this in `<head/>`:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(function() {
    dlg.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
  });
<script>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I'm quite new to jQuery/ASP.NET world and still learning. Where do I put this call?

Comment: Virtually anywhere... You should put it in the onload handler `$(function(){ // code in here });` I'll update with full snippet

Comment: Thanks again. This kind of works; means clicking on the buttons now takes server-side actions, but for some weird reason, I cannot click in the dialog anymore. This is as if the dialog has gone to the background and some invisible layer is in the forefront. Keyboard still works and I can tab through the textboxes and click "Change Password" button.

Comment: You need to use the z-index property and/or use css to bring it to the top. You might also want to (instead of putting as first/last node in the form) create a container at a better position in the DOM. Regards

Comment: z-index doesn't do any good. I'm trying different things. One thing that I forget to mention, I have two links in my `GridView`. One for "Change Password" and another for "Reset Password". Both have their own separate `div`s. Could that be a reason?

Comment: I'm marking this as answer because at least it addresses the original issue. I'll keep looking into it and update this if I find a solution to the secondary problem.

Comment: If you could cobble together the output html etc to reproduce the issue on i.e. http://jsfiddle.net/ i would happily solve

Comment: z-index actually did solve the issue. Problem was that I was applying it to `dlg`, whereas it needed to be applied to `dlg.parent()`. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Because the jQuery Dialogs **re-locate the given part of the page, outside the asp.net form**.

The jQuery Dialogs have been made to include a second form tag, but on asp.net we have the limit of only one form inside the page.

Comment: This is correct... You can work around this by cutting the dialog out of the DOM and reinserting it into the main form

Comment: @PaulSullivan I was searching for the `appendTo` and an example, but you know it better...